# How to check if some product is installed with batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to find if some software is installed in windows. I found below command to find if product is installed

```
wmic product where name="Symantec Endpoint Protection"
```

its output is `No Instance(s) Available.`

I've tried but didn't succeed to store command output in variable in batch file

Comment: wmic outputs Unicode. write it to a file then read it.

Comment: Not able to get output this way "wmic product where name="Symantec Endpoint Protection" >> tmp.txt" 
@Noodles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rid off additional unicode symbols put the result in one more FOR loop:

```
@echo off

for /f  "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in (`wmic product where name^='Symantec Endpoint Protection' 2^>^&1`) do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%%a") do set "result=%%~#"
)

if "%result%" equ "No Instance(s) Available." (
    echo install something
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like this :

```
@echo off
echo   Wait a while .....
wmic product where name="Symantec Endpoint Protection" > %tmp%\tmp.txt
Cmd /U /C Type %tmp%\tmp.txt > %tmp%\Symantec.txt
Start "" %tmp%\Symantec.txt
```